# How to use Docker port in the code for server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

I have Docker image for the web and another image for a server.
My server uses a specific port which I hardcode in the server and in the web. I also define this port in the `docker-compose` file.

I suppose that the right approach would be to specify the port only in the `docker-compose.yml` and then somehow use this port in the code for server and web instead of hardcoding this port in three different places.

Should I use an environment variable in the `docker-compose.yml`? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's been better to just have a server pick its own "normal" port and hard-code that in the places it appears in Docker land.

Let's say I have a server process, maybe that I've written in Go, and I decide it wants to listen on port 12345.  Then:

- The usual Go convention is for the server to take an optional command-line argument like `-bind 0.0.0.0:12345` to specify the bind address and port for the process, but I'd leave this at its default in my Docker container.
- My Dockerfile for the server would `EXPOSE 12345`, mostly as documentation.
- For the client I would explicitly have an option `-server_url http://server:12345` that I could also set via an environment variable `SERVER_URL=http://server:12345`.  Its default might be to point at `localhost` for the easiest developer-oriented setup.
- In my `docker-compose.yml` I'd have to explicitly mention the port on the right-hand side of the server's `ports:` block, if I had one, and in the client's `SERVER_URL`.

  ```
  version: '3'
  services:
    server:
      build: ./server
      ports: ['12345:12345']
    client:
      build: ./client
      environment:
        SERVER_URL: 'http://server:12345'
      ports: ['24680:24680']
  ```

Note that `ports:` is *optional*, you don't need it if you don't want the ability to connect to the back-end service from outside Docker.  Also note that the ports don't need to be the same, and there's merit to using the "normal" ports for things whenever possible.  If the server used ordinary HTTP port 80, I wouldn't have to explicitly mention it in the client URL, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Docker Compose supports [Env files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/), which allow you to declare all of your environment variables. You can then substitute the port number [using one of the env variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).

An env file is generally good practice, because it can be easily swapped out when switching to another environment (e.g. development vs. production), *and* you can set values on-the-fly through the command line, immediately before running your code.

There are good libraries available for many programming languages that support reading these files, such as [Dotenv for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).